# replace quantity expressed in units

Tags: regex

I need to replace quantity specifications buried deep inside strings with "".

For example in the strings below I need to replace the " N pc".

```
(1)["foo (4pc) foo"]   //-> ["foo foo"]
(2)["foo foo 4PC."]     //-> ["foo foo"]
(3)["foo [foo 5 pc]"] //-> ["foo [foo]"]
(4)["foo 5 pc foo"]         //->  ["foo foo"]
```

The substring is always some "qty of pc", but sometimes it has a period and sometimes it is enclosed in parentheses of brackets. If the brackets/parens contain other text, I need to keep them (see (3)). If the brackets/paren only contain the qty-specification, i need to remove them along with the quantity spec (see (1))
If there is whitespace *before* the qty-spec, that also needs top be removed.

// I can't really formulate anything at this point beyond replacing the "pc" substring. Apologies for the flatout "how do i do do all this" question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
\(*\d+[^\d]*pc[\).]*\s*
```

You can try something like this.See demo.

https://regex101.com/r/wU7sQ0/42

Comment: Changed the above answer to better satisfy requirements (whitespace and breckets): \s*\(*\[*\d+[^\d]*pc[\).\]]*

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest this one `/\s\(?\d\s?(pc)\)?\.?/gmi`.

Test: https://regex101.com/r/zJ9dD1/1